# UIbutton on UItableView Cell not clickable

Tags: iphone, uitableview, button, uibutton, click

I have added uibutton in a cell in uitable view. I want this button to be pressed and interat with user. I added this line of code in cell implementation class.

```
readMore = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(180, 50, 67, 25)];
[readMore addTarget:self action:@selector(readMoreClic:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[readMore setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"readmore.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];      
[self addSubview:readMore];
```

the problem is that it is not clicked (it is always in highlight state after selecting the cell). I tried :-

```
1- [self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
2- cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

but I still get cells selected and highlighted with blue color and button not clicked. even after i've chosen

```
[self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray]
```

some one help plz
thx

[note i have a textView in the same cell and it allows interaction (select and copy) ]
[i am using xcode 4 with iOS 4.3]

Comment: This will not fix your issue but you should add the button to the `contentView` rather than the directly to the cell.

Comment: already tried it. same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

try a different control event?:

```
[readMore addTarget:self action:@selector(readMoreClic:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Comment: button not getting darker when i klik it.the prolemm is not on event handler. I just want to see the button get clicked regardless the action taken.

Comment: ah, if I now understand you correctly, you're not having a problem with the button working (i.e. readMoreClic gets called). You simply don't get to see the button visually change if the parent cell is highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

well, i don't quite understand why your button don't respond, because i've came across similar problems but i've used different solutions. here's what i've done:

```
CGRect reuseableRect = CGRectMake(20, 290, 260, 37);

self.actionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
self.actionButton.frame = reuseableRect;

[self.actionButton setTitle:@"Initialize" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.actionButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(performAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:self.actionButton];
```

Actually, i did this :

```
self.actionButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:reuseableRect];
```

but it didn't work. so i changed it into

```
self.actionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

the resueableRect is just a CGRect that I've used all through the view initialization.

as for the three lines of your previous solution, the first one:

```
[self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

it's doing some configurations to the tableView and its cells, so it's not going to affect the button

the second one:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

it's not configuring the button as well, what's more, since the cell is the super view of the button, this line prevents any user interactions.

the third one is not doing anything to the button as well, so i recommend that you delete all of them if you were thinking about configuring the button

Comment: i know about (UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone) and (UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone) but i've read in onother post that it solve the problem. besides i want cells not getting selected when user click it only buttons (i dont want the blue color when cell selected)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do anything with selection style or `userInteractionEnabled`. Make sure that `readMoreClic:` looks like:

```
-(void)readMoreClic:(id)sender
{
}
```

Comment: button not getting darker when i klik it.the prolemm is not on event handler. I just want to see the button get clicked regardless the action taken.